# Flash client and <...> server

Tags: flash, apache-flex, client-server, ria

If you were going to write flash-based RIA, what language would you chose for server?

Any thoughts are appreciated! Thank you in advance!

**UPD**: Well, let's say I'm going to write texteditor. Database on server is MongoDB. So it's likely that client and server communicated via JSON. Serialized blocks of text re astored in DB, so the server gets them from DB and sends them to client or updates them. The major functionality should be on client side. The server also should be able to export documents to TeX format.

Comment: It all depends on what you want to achieve really..
Therefore your question is rather vague. Could you please elaborate on some of the features your server and client should provide?

Comment: As Dennis mentioned it all depends on what you want to achieve. Java and PHP are popular choices though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Flash player 11 and AIR 3 are out, you will be able to leverage [native JSON support](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html) client side.

Therefore, if you intend to use JSON anyway it does not really matter which server side technology you use. As Rob already mentioned, Java and Php are often used for this purpose.

Keep in mind though that using AMF will have some performance benefits and will allow you to transport typed objects without the need to manually parse them.

Answer (score 1):

If you would use Adobe Flex on the client side and you have some java skills I would recommend to use Java on the server side. Another question is if you really want to create a web application or desktop application (AIR not FLex).